# Changing C to MIPS and bitwise or

Tags: c, mips

b = 25 | a; 
Assume that a corresponds to register $t0 and b corresponds to register $t1.?
Can anyone explain how to approach this and can give me the final answer so I can compare with mine after I do it?

Comment: What is your question? You want to know the assembly instruction?

Comment: I did but I think I got it (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you mean `ori $t1, $t0, 25`? That would be the equivalent.

You can find tons of references about MIPS with a Google search. A good example would be this [MIPS instruction reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html).

Comment: Yes thank you, I was unclear on that. Thank you for the website, really helped.